# How to give the path name for plist?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Actually, it works if I add the `plist` to the resource folder. But, if I create a folder and add the `plist` to that folder, it does not work.
Can anybody help me? I am totally new to cocos 2d and also to plist.

Comment: how it does not work? please provide more detail or code you implemented so we can help and what exactly happening?-Is your plist file not being created?-if yes,then please check using breakpoint weather array or dictionary you writing to plist is allocated or not?

Answer (score 0):

after getting resource path add your folder  Name.

Comment: Ya ofcourse Ayaz.. But it is not able to fetch the corresponding image from the plist.Its crashing showing file not found error.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

plistpath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Product.plist"]];
```

And then

```
[array writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; 

[Whatever [Array or Dictionary] you want to Write in Plist]
```

And To fetch Data From Plist

```
NSmutableArray *Yourarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistpath];
```